# convert htmlelement to string for comparison javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using a function that obtains a target element id at onclick. Example, if I click on the text element that has the id of  'help'.

```
var click = (e && e.target) || (event && event.srcElement);
```

The var click would contain the ref to the id of "help".

I want to compare the var click to the string 'help' using the if statement below.

```
if (click == 'about') {do something}
```

The comparison does not work because the var click is not a string.  When I use the alert(click) to debug, it shows click as "object HTMLElement".

How would you compare whether the id 'help' is obtained from var click?

I could write out something like

```
if (click == document.getElementById('help')) {do something}
```

but that would make a long statement.

also

if the var click is `document.getElementById('help')`, how would I create a new var "div" as `document.getElementById('helpdiv')` by adding the word "div" in the id of the var click?

basically, I want to use the same function to generate dynamic responses to each element that was clicked on, and not having to create a separate function for each element.

```
if (click.id == 'help'){
var link = click;
var divid = click.id+'div';
var div = document.getElementById(divid);
alert (div.id); //helpdiv string
}
```

TIA for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```
var click = (e && e.target) || (event && event.srcElement);
```

is not getting the `id` rather the element itself, use **[`getAttribute`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/getAttribute)** to get the id instead.

```
var id = click.getAttribute('id');
alert(id);
```

Or simply:

```
var id = click.id;
alert(id);
```

So your condition now becomes:

```
if (id == 'about') {do something}
```

and

```
if (id == document.getElementById('help')) {do something}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is a very helpful explanation of the properties.  I wonder if you could address the last part of my question.

Comment: @Jamex: sure but you should be more specific about it or probably now you can get an idea from the example code i have posted.

Comment: Hi Sarfraz, I just posted the code that I created to address the last part of my question, but I feel that there is a shorter method.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is probably

```
if (click.id == 'help') { //do something }
```

Comment: Thank you, that was easy.  Do you mind addressing the last part of my question (that I appended to the original question)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (click["id"] != null && click["id"] == "help") { do stuff }
```

Addressing the last part of your question, you cannot create a new DOM object by modifying your current one like you propose in your question, and I do not understand if you want to locate an already existing object and store it in a variable, or create a new one from scratch, so :

If you want to find a new one, and you know its named like "show" + the id of your current click variable, you can easily do:

```
if (click["id"] != null) { 
    var found = document.getElementById("show" + click["id"]);
}
```

Or if you intend to create a new one :

```
if (click["id"] != null) { 
    var created = document.createElement("div"); // replace with whatever you need
    created["id"] = "show" + click["id"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after ...

```
if (click.id == 'help') {  // Test to see if click is the 'help' element
  var newEl = document.createElement('div');  // Create a new element
  newEl.id = click.id + 'div';  // Set it's id
  newEl.innerHTML = 'my help text goes here'; // Set it's content
  click.parentElement.appendChild(newEl);  // Add it to the document immediately following the 'click' element
}
```

Be aware that the name of an element is not the same as the element itself.  Just making a new element name by appending 'div' to some existing name does not, in and of itself, create a new element.  You have to explicitely create a new element object and add it into the document, as shown above.

Comment: Thank you broofa.  Your perspective is very helpful.